# Hover element affects another inside another div

Tags: css, hover, element

I have the following code and I want to do this: when `.userPicture` is on hover the class name should change. How do I do that?

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="userPicture"></a>
    <div class="contentNew">
        <div class="date">17 Jul</div>
        <div class="description">
            <a href="#" class="name">Jose</a> published a product
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: The ideia was when the "userPicture" is on hover, the class "name" (inside desctiption) change the color.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need to achieve. If you simply want to style element on mouse hover then it's much better to use :hover css selector.
But if you need some additional logics then javascript usage is required.

It could be done this way:

```
 <li>
       <a href="#" class="userPicture" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('class', 'userPicture-hovered');" onmouseleave="this.setAttribute('class', 'userPicture');"></a>
          <div class="contentNew">
            <div class="date">17 Jul</div>
            <div class="description">
                <a href="#" class="name">Jose</a> published a product
            </div>
          </div>
 </li>
```

Example with inline javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/rw9dcg5d/

Example with css `:hover`: https://jsfiddle.net/539wep5g/

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to change the class name, you can do it with javascript. But as @Yura Yakym mentioned, css :hover is probably a better approach.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".userPicture");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var defaultClassName = a[i].className;
  a[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.className = "userPicture-hover"
  });
  a[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    this.className = defaultClassName
  });
}
```

```css
.userPicture-hover {
  background: #c00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="userPicture">User picture</a>
    <div class="contentNew">
      <div class="date">17 Jul</div>
      <div class="description">
        <a href="#" class="name">Jose</a> published a product
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="userPicture">User picture</a>
    <div class="contentNew">
      <div class="date">17 Jul</div>
      <div class="description">
        <a href="#" class="name">Jose</a> published a product
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```